# Flash, Internet Explorer and 60fps speed

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, frame-rate

I have created a Flash game which plays at **60 frames per second**. It plays fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer 8 and 9; in these cases, it seems to be half (or less than half) the intended frame rate.

I have tried embedding it even by using Flash Authoring Tool's own html code, as well as the swfobject method, but to no avail. In all cases, **GPU acceleration** is enabled.

It's also not a matter of CPU performance, since it is tested on the same computer with all other applications closed. The problem only rises with IE.

One final peculiarity to consider : I have loaded FRAPS to count the actual rendering frame rate and it shows it to be **60 fps** (inside IE), although it's crystal clear that this is not the actual speed achieved.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - in my case it goes at full speed when you move the mouse around over the flash window, which I guess forces IE to re-request the frame.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like flash isn't properly installed on your IE browser

Try the following (assuming you have Adobe Flash Player v10.2 installed):

• Restart your computer.

• Open Internet Options (located in the Control Panel).

• Click on the Advanced tab.

• Click on the Reset button, place a check next to Delete Personal Settings and then click Reset.

• Launch IE9 and Adobe Flash Player will be properly enabled.

then try your tests again

Comment: I have tried on several different computers. All have latest (v11.2) Player. It can't be the case that they all had the Flash Player wrongly installed!

Comment: Remember IE9 uses the ActiveX version of Flash and is totally seperate to the version used by Firefox/Chrome etc.

Answer (score 0):

GPU acceleration is not always the best solution. It depends on the way you have code the app.

Try another [wmode](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_) value.